# how to use Ezar with ionic3

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm trying to implement ezar to ionic but can't use it. I did ionic cordova plugin add com.ezartech.ezar.videooverlay

```
window["plugins"].ezar
      .initializeVideoOverlay(
      function () {
        window["plugins"].ezar.getBackCamera().start();
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';

      },
      function (err) {
        alert('unable to init ezar: ' + err);
      });
```

It can't find ezar says undefined
I tried without window[] but couldn't succeed it also I can't import at ts file because its not installed as a component. Do you have any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
var win: any = window;
      if (win.ezar) {
           var ezar: any = win.ezar;
              ezar.initializeVideoOverlay(
               function() {  
                   ezar.getBackCamera().start();
               },
               function(err) {  alert(JSON.stringify(err));
               }, {fitWebViewToCameraView: true});
       } else {
           alert('Unable to detect the ezAR plugin');
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try window["ezar"] in place of window["plugins"].ezar

Worked for me (although getting ezAR to work with ionic 3 in general is quite difficult with the lack of documentation)